# (Un)Limit CPU usage - Windows - Mathematica

Tags: windows, optimization, wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-8

I'm programming in Mathematica 8.

When I run my programme, I check with Win8 task manager that the CPU usage is at 35% as soon as it starts to run, and my memory usage also increases to 44%. Does Win8 limit the amount of CPU usage that a certain programme may have? I need to make my computer to use more of its resources to run the programme faster.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: More likely, Mathematica isn't able to use all of the CPU. Not everything is perfectly parallelizable.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening here is a common misconception about how processors approach problems involving heavy computation.

Although you may indeed have a powerful 4-core processing machine, and you have a program which is capable of using all 4 processing cores (which mathematica definitely is!), unless the code is written in a parallel fashion, you will only be able to use 1 core at a time to do  the calculations. As Mysticial mentioned in the comment, not all code is parallelizable, in fact, I'd say a great many problems are not inherently able to be parallelized.

Check [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/120808/what-are-some-common-examples-of-a-parallelizable-problem) for some good examples of problems that can be split up in a parallel fashion well. Now, your memory usage will simply increase with the size of the data that's being stored temporarily. (ex: storing a 69X69 matrix takes up less memory (RAM) than a 4000X4000, being parallel has little to do with this, and more with the problem itself).

Anyway, tl;dr, your computer is acting normally. To use all 100% of that 4-core machine you're using, check out [This](https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/ParallelComputing.html) mathematica reference guide to parallel operations.